# Exercise XIX number 15 - Calculus Made Easy

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, hyperbolic-functions

$$
\text{Use substitution}\quad\frac{1}{x}=\frac{b}{a}cosh\;u\quad\text{to show that}\quad\\
\int\;\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}=\frac{1}{a}\ln\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}{x}\;+\;C.\\
\text{My way:}\\
\text{Let}\quad\frac{1}{x}=\frac{b}{a}cosh\;u\quad\\
x=\frac{a}{b}\frac{1}{cosh\;u}\\
dx=-\frac{a}{b}\frac{sinh\;u}{cosh^2u}du\\
x^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\frac{1}{cosh^2u}\\
u=cosh^-(\frac{a}{bx})\\
\int\frac{\frac{b\;cosh\;u}{a}\cdot-\frac{a\;sinh\;u}{b\;cosh^2u}}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2\cdot\frac{a^2}{b^2\;cosh^2u}}}du=\\
=\int\frac{-\frac{sinh\;u}{cosh\;u}=-tanh\;u}{\sqrt{a^2-\frac{a^2}{cosh^2u}}=\sqrt{a^2(1-\frac{1}{cosh^2u})}=\sqrt{a^2\;tanh^2u}=a\;tanh\;u}du=\\
=\int-\frac{du}{a}=\quad-\frac{1}{a}\int du=\quad -\frac{u}{a}\quad+\quad C
=\quad-\frac{1}{a}cosh^-(\frac{a}{bx})\quad+\quad C=\\
=\quad-\frac{1}{a}\ln\Biggr(\frac{a}{bx}\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2x^2}-1}\Biggr)\quad+\quad C=\\
=\quad-\frac{1}{a}\ln\Biggr(\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}{bx}\Biggr)\quad+\quad C=\\
=\quad-\frac{1}{a}\biggr(\ln(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2})-\ln(bx)\biggr)\quad+\quad C=\\
=\quad\frac{1}{a}\biggr(\ln(bx)-\ln(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2})\biggr)\quad+\quad C=\\
=\quad\frac{1}{a}\ln\frac{bx}{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}\quad+\quad C\\\text{What went wrong?}
$$

Comment: I would use the Euler Substitution

Comment: Just because two expressions don't look the same doesn't mean they aren't equal. Have you tried rationalizing the denominator in your expression? You also have a constant of integration that can absorb some of the difference. I'm not saying that your answer is necessarily right, but have you checked to see that it's actually different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have a minor error: $\cosh^-(\frac{a}{bx})= \ln\left(\frac{a}{bx} + \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2x^2} - 1}\right)$, the minus-sign is not correct. This gives you
$$\int\;\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}\quad = \quad\frac{1}{a}\ln\frac{bx}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}+ C \\ = \quad \frac{1}{a}\ln\frac{b^2x}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}} - \frac{1}{a}\ln b + C 
$$
But
$$\frac{b^2x}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}  \quad = \quad\frac{b^2x(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2})}{(a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2})(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2})} \\
= \quad\frac{b^2x(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2})}{a^2 -(a^2-b^2x^2)} \quad = \quad\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}}{x}$$